# CSS3 gradient jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

[image: slider]

What is the smartest way to make this a jQuery slider? I don't know exactly how to do the gradient on the left and right side.

Comment: `:fist-child` and `:last-child` on the slider images with a gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, with a container `div` with two child `div`s: one for the images and one for the gradient. For the sliding, you can animate the image `div`'s `left` property using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/SSNmT/2/

Not tested on Opera, but works on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This [LINK](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) can help you maybe with the gradient. The container should has the gradient style, not the elements. So you can easily make a slider in that container.